# Install pycrypto on Mac OS X without gcc

Tags: python, macos, gcc, installation, pycrypto

I'm trying to install pycrypto because it's one of the dependencies for ansible. I know that gcc can be installed on Mac by installing Xcode Command Line Tools but I don't want to install Xcode because its installation can't be automated. (I need to do it on many client computers)

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330678/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-on-google-compute-engine) but it addresses linux system and not OS X.

Is there any way to install pycrypto or any similar package without gcc?

Comment: You can install just the Xcode Command Line Tools without Xcode by running  `xcode-select --install` (at least on newer OSXs). This does pop up a confirmation window, so I am not sure how easily this can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could  build pycrpyto, install locally (i.e. to $HOME) and then distribute this to the other machines